# How can i save the conditions in variable and use that variable in rails active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am trying to save the conditions in a variable and call that in the active record query as shown below

```
if !key1.nil?
  @condition = ":key2 => @value2, :key3 => @value3"
else
  @condition = ":key4 => @value4, :key5 => @value5"
end

@result = Model.where(@condition).all
```

How can i do this? please help me.

**UPDATE:**

```
  @condition = { "key1 = ? and key2 >= ? and key3 <= ? and id IN (?)", @value1, @value2, @value3, @id }
```

Comment: Try "key1 = #{@val1} and key2 >= #{@val2} and key3 <= #{@val3} and id IN (#{@id})"

Answer (score 0):

Use `hash` instead of `string`:

```
 @condition =  { :key2 => @value2, :key3 => @value3 }
```

Also, you could probably simplify the syntax of `if !key1.nil?` by using `unless`:

```
@condition = {}
unless key1
  @condition =  { :key2 => @value2, :key3 => @value3 }
else
  @condition =  { :key4 => @value4, :key5 => @value5 }
end
```

Comment: ok if suppose i have my condition like shown in the update, it shows an error.